# angular-chart.js, Chart.js v2 legend customization. How?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

In the documentation there is `legendCallback` and `generateLabels` and I don't understand the documentation that much. Given my code below. How can I change the legends to make it into one legend per line,have a background and line chart legend should look like a line not a bar or in short how to customize the legend.

JS:

```
vm.labels = ['2015 - Aug', '2015 - Sept', '2015 - Oct', '2015 - Nov', '2015 - Dec', '2016 - Jan',
    '2016 - Feb', '2016 - Mar', '2016 - April', '2016 - May', '2016 - Jun', '2016 - Jul', '2016 - Aug',
];
vm.series = [
    'A',
    'B',
];
vm.data = [
    [14, 12, 17, 24, 29, 17, 23, 10, 16, 20, 33, 5, 8],
    [50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50],
];

vm.colors = [
    {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,104,26,1)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(0,104,26,1)',
    },
    {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(56,80,143,1)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(56,80,143,1)',
    },
];

vm.options = {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [
            {
                ticks: {
                    callback: function (value) {
                        var values = value.split(' ');
                        var date = [values[0], values[2]];
                        return date;
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
        yAxes: [
            {
                ticks: {
                    max: 100,
                    min: 0,
                    step: 20,
                    callback: function (value) {
                        return value + '%';
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    },

    // legend
    legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'bottom',
    },

    // title
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Chart',
        fontSize: 15,
    },

    // hover
    hover: {
        mode: 'single',
    },

    // tooltips
    tooltips: {
        enabled: true,
        mode: 'single',
        callbacks: {
            title: function (tooltipItems, data) {
                var idx = tooltipItems[0].datasetIndex;
                var year = tooltipItems[0].xLabel[0];
                var month = tooltipItems[0].xLabel[1];
                if (idx === 0) {
                    return year + '-' + month;
                } else {
                    return '';
                }
            },

            label: function (tooltipItems, data) {
                var idx = tooltipItems.datasetIndex;
                var dataidx = tooltipItems.index;
                var seriesValue = data.datasets[idx].label;
                var value = data.datasets[idx].data[dataidx];
                if (idx === 0) {
                    return seriesValue + ': ' + value + '%';
                } else {
                    return seriesValue + ' (' + value + '%)';
                }
            },
        },
    },
};

vm.datasetOverride = [];
for (var i = 0; i < vm.series.length; i++) {
    vm.datasetOverride.push(
        {
            lineTension: 0,
            fill: false,
            pointStyle: 'circle',
            pointRadius: 0,
            pointHoverRadius: 4,
            pointHitRadius: 10,
            type: 'line',
        }
    );
}

vm.datasetOverride[1].borderDash = [5, 1];
```

HTML

```
<canvas id="line" 
        class="chart chart-line" 
        chart-data="vm.data"
        chart-labels="vm.labels" 
        chart-series="vm.series" 
        chart-options="vm.options"
        chart-colors="vm.colors"
        chart-dataset-override="vm.datasetOverride"></canvas>
```

Currently:
[image]